# Stop all webkit-animation on hover

Tags: html, css

Hello guys I'm trying to stop all animation when I hover on animated elements but it only pauses each element separately

```
    .wtfigo:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
     }
#productstrategy,#businessd,#boardst,#coinfin,#mbdpng,#phonepng,#musanan {

    position: absolute;
    left: 880px;
    top: 425px;

    -webkit-animation: myOrbit 10s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Safari 5 */
       -moz-animation: myOrbit 10s linear infinite; /* Firefox 5-15 */
         -o-animation: myOrbit 10s linear infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
            animation: myOrbit 10s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, 
                                                      IE 10+, Safari 5 */     
}
@-webkit-keyframes myOrbit {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(300px) rotate(0deg); }
    to   { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(300px) rotate(-360deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes myOrbit {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(300px) rotate(0deg); }
    to   { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(300px) rotate(-360deg); }
}

@-o-keyframes myOrbit {
    from { -o-transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(300px) rotate(0deg); }
    to   { -o-transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(300px) rotate(-360deg); }
}

@keyframes myOrbit {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(300px) rotate(0deg); }
    to   { transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(300px) rotate(-360deg); }
}


<div class="wtfigo"><div id="productstrategy"><img src=".../PS.png"><h3 style="color:white;">Product Strategy</h3></div>
<div style="animation-delay: 1.42s;" id="businessd"><img src=".../BD.png"><h3 style="color:white;text-align:center;">Business Development</h3></div>
<div style="animation-delay: 2.84s;" id="boardst"><img src=".../board.png"><h3 style="color:white;text-align:center;">Operations</h3></div>
<div style="animation-delay: 4.26s;" id="coinfin"><img src=".../coin.png"><h3 style="color:white;text-align:center;">Financial Advisors</h3></div>
<div style="animation-delay: 5.68s;" id="mbdpng"><img src=".../MBD.png"><h3 style="color:white;text-align:center;">Marketing<br />Brand<br />Degital</h3></div>
<div style="animation-delay: 7.1s;" id="phonepng"><img src=".../phone.png"><h3 style="color:white;text-align:center;">Call Center</h3></div>
<div style="animation-delay: 8.52s;" id="musanan"><img src=".../musanan.png"><h3 style="color:white;text-align:center;">Insurance</h3></div>
</div>
```

Please let me know if there is any way I can pause all animations on hover

Cheers

Comment: try `:not(:hover)` in your css selector for the animation instead of stopping animation with `animation-play-state: paused`

Comment: thank you for your quick reply,

You mean like this ?

#productstrategy,#businessd,#boardst,#coinfin,#mbdpng,#phonepng,#musanan:not(:hover) {

Comment: I added an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your animation to a single parent selector so that you can pause it via the same. See simplified code below:

```
<style>
    #productstrategy,
    #businessd,
    #boardst,
    #coinfin,
    #mbdpng,
    #phonepng,
    #musanan {
        position: absolute;
        left: 880px;
        top: 425px;
    }

    .wtfigo .flyingthing {
        animation: myOrbit 10s linear infinite;
    }

    .wtfigo:hover .flyingthing {
        animation-play-state: paused;
    }

    @keyframes myOrbit {
        from { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(300px) rotate(0deg); }
        to   { transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(300px) rotate(-360deg); }
    }
</style>

<div class="wtfigo"><div id="productstrategy"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"><h3 style="color:white;">Product Strategy</h3></div>
<div class="flyingthing" style="animation-delay: 1.42s;" id="businessd"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"><h3 style="color:white;text-align:center;">Business Development</h3></div>
<div class="flyingthing" style="animation-delay: 2.84s;" id="boardst"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"><h3 style="color:white;text-align:center;">Operations</h3></div>
<div class="flyingthing" style="animation-delay: 4.26s;" id="coinfin"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"><h3 style="color:white;text-align:center;">Financial Advisors</h3></div>
<div class="flyingthing" style="animation-delay: 5.68s;" id="mbdpng"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"><h3 style="color:white;text-align:center;">Marketing<br />Brand<br />Degital</h3></div>
<div class="flyingthing" style="animation-delay: 7.1s;" id="phonepng"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"><h3 style="color:white;text-align:center;">Call Center</h3></div>
<div class="flyingthing" style="animation-delay: 8.52s;" id="musanan"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"><h3 style="color:white;text-align:center;">Insurance</h3></div>
```

> You have to make sure your `wtfigo` div fills the area that should be hoverable to stop the animation though.

Comment: thank you Dominik, 

I applied the code but unfortunately when I hover now it starts animating all over again

Comment: You want it to stop on hover, right? I try this in my browser here and it stops... not sure what is wrong...

Comment: Are you sure you did this right? I triple checked ... it works on all browsers here

Comment: Oh I get you now... you want to pause the animation where it is and resume when you blur the cursor... ahh Will make change to the answer

Comment: Well, I guess you got me wrong, basically i want it to pause instead of killing the whole process, I want all elements stops moving when I hover on one of them

Sorry for being annoying !!

Comment: If that works for my please remember to upvote and mark as answer @WilliamI.Watfeh

Comment: Awesome Mate it worked perfectly Cheers , you are the best

Comment: @WilliamI.Watfeh to mark an answer as the correct one please click the gray tick on the left side of it.